# Unrecognized attribute 'decompressionEnabled'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have created a web application in asp.net 4.0 and added external webservice to application.
(http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx)
When I run this application I got below error.

In web.config decompressionEnabled="true" it shows an error.

Any sloution?

Comment: Line 139:                    <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
Line 140:                        maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
Line 141:                        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
Line 142:                        keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
Line 143:                        realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"

Comment: Line 139:                    <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
Line 140:                        maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
Line 141:                        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
Line 142:                        keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
Line 143:                        realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project --> Property pages --> Build --> set TargetFramework 4 or greater.